# \includepdfmerge starting new documents on right side page

Tags: pdfpages

I'm using `pdfjam` to merge a large number of PDF files for subsequent printing. Because I don't want to have pages from different documents on the same physical sheet of paper, I want to issue a `\cleardoublepage` after every document (I have one page per sheet, but I'm printing double-sided). From the `pdfjam` source I found that the core of the call is `\includepdfmerge[$miscOptions]{$filePageList}`. So then the question is: *is there any option for `\includepdfmerge` that will have the effect of `\cleardoublepage` before every inserted document*?

I tried:

- `pdfjam --openright`, but this simply unconditionally inserts an empty page before the first page of the document.
- `pdfjam --pagecommand '\\cleardoublepage'`, I had expected this to add empty pages between all pages (not what I want), but tried anyway; it fails with `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`.

---

Note: The reason I want a single PDF is because the actual process of sending the document to the printer is a bit involved, so I rather have one document with very many pages, than many small documents.

Comment: To pass an option to `\includepdfmerge` use e.g. `--pagecommand={\\cleardoublepage}`.  However, that will not do want you want, it is just a command executed between the output pages.  What you really need to is rewrite the script so it produces a sequence of commands `\includepdf[$options]{$file1}\clearpage\includepdf[$options]{$file2}..`, which is not too hard a perl exercise, but is not really relevant to a latex site.

Comment: @AndrewSwann That's what I ended up doing in practice (it was small enough to do by hand), question is if I can do that in LaTeX by passing appropriate commands.

Comment: You can do something similar in latex using one of the many looping constructs, there many examples on this site, but this would be using `\includepdf`.  The `\includepdfmerge` has no such option and I see no simple modification you can make to its code to effect that.